# Can Pandas Bin into a Dynamic Number of Bins?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just came across pandas.cut and I know it supports binning into an equal number of bins.  I'm using this in one of my Python scripts to do some binning and it works great.  This is what I am using now.

```
modDF['RatingDecile'] = pd.cut(modDF['Rating'], 10, labels=False)
```

I'm wondering if there is a function that supports some kind of dynamic binning, based on very long 'tails' of data.  I have a few fields in a dataframe that have something like 90-95% of the data distributed pretty evenly among 10 bins, but the other 5-10%, should probably be spread among another 30 or 40 bins.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What determines the boundary of a bin? If you want to make it dynamic, how do you determine how many bins there should be?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with.  I can define it, just like I'm doing now.  However, I would like to see if the dataset itself can offer some guidance as to how many bins need to be used.  Is there a way to get 90% into 10 bins, and 10% in maybe 20 bins or maybe 30 bins?  Is that possible?